# How to merge two files and sort into one file?

Tags: python, file

Suppose I have two sorted huge files:

File A:

```
1
1
2
3
5
...
```

File B:

```
2
2
2
4
8
...
```

When I load any file in memory, it will cause crash, maybe it's issue of lack memory. I am thinking how to load the two files in the same to merge and sort into a file. How do I do?

---

Hello, everyone!

This is my originally idea:

```
def read_lines(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        cxt = f.read()
        lines = cxt.split('\n')
        return lines

a = read_lines('a.txt')
b = read_lines('b.txt')
c = a + b
c.sort()

with open('c.txt', 'w') as f:
    lines = '\n'.join(c)
    f.write(lines)
```

Comment: Your idea is already good. At what point (opening files, reading line-by-line, merging two sequences, writing output) do you have troubles?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: @Signal I have showed my code.

Comment: Unless you really *have* to do this in Python, this problem is well suited to shell scripting, e.g. with bash `cat a.txt b.txt | sort > c.txt`

Comment: @HumphreyTriscuit Absolutely!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As both file are sorted (and greater than 0) the you just need to merge them. Just off the top of my head and not tested:

```
with open('a.txt') as fa, open('b.txt') as fb, open('new.txt', 'w') as fn:
    line_a, line_b = int(next(fa, 0)), int(next(fb, 0))
    while line_a or line_b:
        if not line_b or (line_a and line_a < line_b):
            fn.write("{}\n".format(line_a))
            line_a = int(next(fa, 0))
        else:
            fn.write("{}\n".format(line_b))
            line_b = int(next(fb, 0))
```

Comment: This is the right idea as it avoids reading in the entirety of both files

Comment: It's only meant as an outline... not tested. What error is it presenting.

Answer (score 0):

If my any file includes negative numbers, the answer of @AChampion isn't well suited to solve it.

So I have another answer. It solves not only my original question but also files includes negative numbers.

```
def nexline(f):
    return float(next(f, '-inf'))

def is_end(line):
    return line == float('-inf')

def write_new_line(new_f, source_f, line):
    new_f.write("{}\n".format(line))
    source_line = nexline(source_f)
    return source_line

with open('a.txt') as fa, open('b.txt') as fb, open('new.txt', 'w') as fn:
    line_a, line_b = nexline(fa), nexline(fb)
    while not is_end(line_a) or not is_end(line_b):
        if not is_end(line_a) and line_a < line_b:
            line_a = write_new_line(fn, fa, line_a)
        else:
            line_b = write_new_line(fn, fb, line_b)
```